# C alternative to malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

While reading K&R (section 6.5, second edition) I have encountered the following function:

```
struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return (struct tnode *) malloc( sizeof(struct tnode) );
}
```

the function allocates some spaces to store a struct tnode. I just want to check my understanding by asking whether I would achieve the same with:

```
struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    struct tnode s;
    return &s;
}
```

Comment: the second code snipit will NOT work because it is returning a pointer to an item on a local stack.  the local stack becomes undefined when it goes out of scope, as when the function exits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is no.

```
struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return (strcut tnode *) malloc( sizeof(strcut tnode) );
}
```

`malloc` allocates space which can be used afterwards, oftentimes the space is allocated on the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP). Space which is allocated with `malloc` needs to be free'd manually when you don't need it any more - otherwise you will get a memory leak. This pointer can be used after the function returned.

In the following example

```
strcut tnode *talloc(void)
{
    struct tnode s;
    return &s;
}
```

the struct is allocated on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and automatically free'd when the function exits. Thus, your returned pointer becomes a dangling pointer which you cannot use (outside the function). Using a scoped object outside its scope is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: a follow up question: in the second example will the returned pointer points to NULL or to some unpredictable place in the memory?

Comment: The pointer will point to the address of the struct on the stack (!=NULL).

Comment: but under this address on the stuck there will be something which is not my s I declared inside the function, right?

Comment: @SergeyZykov There may or may not be something, since that memory under returned address will be undefined after you return from that function. It's an error to do so anyway.

Comment: IIRC the returned pointer value will be "indeterminate", i.e. it won't be safe to even look at, let alone dereference. Technically it won't have to be an "address".

Comment: There are no guarantees about "`malloc` is on the heap, local values go on the stack". There *is* undefined behaviour about locally declared objects being used after program execution leaves the scope.

Comment: @Rhymoid Thanks for pointing this out in a more detailled way!

Answer (score 1):

When code calls `malloc`, the system gives a pointer to a region of memory which the system promises not to use *for any other purpose* until that pointer is passed to `free` or `realloc`.  In your second example, the declaration reserves an area of storage large enough to hold a `struct tnode` and guarantees that the storage will not be reused until execution leaves the block(*).  Once execution leaves the block, the storage that had been used to hold the `struct tnode` will be *eligible to be reused for other purposes*.

(*) An implementation might use the storage for other purposes in cases where doing so would have no observable effect on program behavior, but programmers generally shouldn't need to worry about that.